# send json and html at the same time

Tags: java, html, json, servlets

I implemented a SOA service using other services(I'm using java language). I use servlet to display an html table with the processed results. Is it also possible to send json with html? or in other words is it possible to send two different things in the response of the doPost method of httpservlet?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your html page to access the json you could embed the data within a script tag:

```
<script type="application/javascript">

    var mydata = {"foo":"bar"};

</script>
```